# How to enable Hyper-V in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v, emulator, windows-phone

I've got a Windows 8 (not .1, not Pro; OEM with a Lenovo Z580 laptop), which I want to use for WP8 development.

I've read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), and a few more articles.

I have enabled in BIOS what looks like it has to do with hardware virtualisation - "Intel Virtual Technology" (is this VMX?). No signs of EPT or XD.

I've got the four Hyper-V items in the enumeration that msinfo32 shows.

However, in the 'Control Panel/Programs and Features/Turn on|off windows features' list, I don't have Hyper-V.

Is this available at all on my machine, and if not what can I do to get it working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hyper-V is only a feature within Windows 8.x Professional.  Your only other alternative is to upgrade your installation to Windows 8.x Professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to everything I have read, you have to have Win8 Pro or Enterprise in order to have the built-in HyperV client functionality.

<del>If you don't want to upgrade to Pro, try [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) (free) or [VMware Workstation](https://www.virtualbox.org) (not free).</del>

Edit: never mind that last bit.  MSDN login finally went through...

Edit2: well upon further inspection, it seems that there are mixed results getting the WP8 VM working under VirtualBox.  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489555/how-can-i-get-the-windows-8-phone-emulator-to-run-via-virtualbox) & [Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WANk_XaovqM)  YMMV I guess.